# how to catch an error and console log it? Angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

```js
private async getData(): Promise<Array<DataSet>> {
// the next line returns an error
        this.portalConf = await GetProcedure.exe(this.portalId ? this.portalId : PortalStore.getPortalId());
        this.portal = new Portal(this.portalConf.name, this.portalConf.id, this.portalConf.content, '');
        DataSet.resetStore();
        return GetData.getDatasets(this.portal);
    }
```

the "this.conf" line returns an error , how can I catch that error and act on it ?

Comment: `try` and `catch`? This isn't specific to Angular or TypeScript, and is one of the *points* of using `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you show me how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code: simply use try and catch blocks

```js
private async getData(): Promise < Array < DataSet >> {
  try {
    // the next line returns an error
    this.portalConf = await GetProcedure.exe(this.portalId ? this.portalId : PortalStore.getPortalId());
    this.portal = new Portal(this.portalConf.name, this.portalConf.id, this.portalConf.content, '');
    DataSet.resetStore();
    return GetData.getDatasets(this.portal);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
}
```